# Extract the first 50 bytes of a file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script in powershell to pull file information from servers and write the data into a csv file for review.
I have most of the script working very well, however my initial attempt to extract the first line of each file resulted in unexpected results due to some files not having a /cr and therefore printing the whole file contents.

I want to extract the first 50 bytes of each file into the csv but the -TotalCount reads the first line and I have been reading into .NET [IO.File] and [System.Text.Encoding] but cannot find a working method.

My code is currently:

```
    Select-Object FullName,Name,Directory,@{n="Owner";ex={(Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner}},CreationTimeUtc,LastAccessTimeUtc,LastWriteTimeUtc,@{n='Size(MB)';ex={[math]::Round($_.length/1MB, 2)}},
    @{n='MD5';ex={(Get-FileHash $_.fullname).hash}},@{n="Content(UTF8)";ex={(Get-Content $_.fullname -AsByteStream -Raw -TotalCount 50)}} |

    Export-Csv c:\temp\$fn-filelisting.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

It seems that PS used to used bytes as the selection for -TotalCount but have since changed that to read by lines.

Have to use PS due to system restrictions, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: from a quick net search, it looks like `[IO.File]::OpenRead($file)` and then the `.ReadBytes()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to **read the first 50 *characters*, not *bytes***.
Therefore, use a [`System.IO.StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamReader) instance, because `Get-Content` doesn't support reading a given number of *characters*, only *lines*:

```
$charBuf = [char[]]::new(50) # buffer to read into
$textStream = [IO.StreamReader] $_.FullName # create the stream reader
$charCount = $textStream.Read($charBuf, 0, $charBuf.Length) # read into buffer
$textStream.Close() # close the stream
-join $charBuf[0..($charCount-1)] # output the chars. read as a string
```

---

As for what you tried:

> `Get-Content $_.fullname -AsByteStream -Raw -TotalCount 50`

`-AsByteStream` is only supported in *PowerShell [Core] 6+*, where it replaced `-Encoding Byte`.

<sup>This constituted an unfortunate breaking change: see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7986) and [this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/5080#discussion_r144723133).</sup>

In *Windows PowerShell*, `-Encoding Byte` must be used.

`-TotalCount` *is* effective in outputting only the specified number of bytes when combined with `-AsByteStream` / `-Encoding Byte`.

However, parameters `-Raw` and `-TotalCount` are *mutually exclusive*.

While `Get-Content $_.fullname -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 50` / `Get-Content $_.fullname -AsByteStream -TotalCount 50` therefore does work in PowerShell [Core] / Windows PowerShell, it outputs the bytes *one by one*, which is *needlessly slow* if you want to collect all bytes *in memory*.

Therefore, add `-ReadCount 50` in order to read the 50 bytes *at once*, and output them *as a `[byte[]` array*:

```
# Read 50 bytes at once and utput a [byte[]] array

# Windows PowerShell:
Get-Content $_.fullname -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 50 -ReadCount 50

# PowerShell [Core] 6+
Get-Content $_.fullname -AsByteStream -TotalCount 50 -ReadCount 50
```

In *PowerShell [Core] 7*, an optimization is available: `-ReadCount 0` is a shortcut to request that whatever count `-TotalCount` requests be read into a single array:

```
# PowerShell 7
Get-Content $_.fullname -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 50 -ReadCount 0
```

While the above is a fairly efficient way of extracting the first 50 *bytes*, converting them to *characters*:

- is cumbersome, because you need to know the source character encoding and convert the bytes to text based on it.
- but, more importantly, can result in reading an *incomplete* character with input files that use *variable-length* encodings, notably UTF-8, if the 50-byte boundary happens to fall in the middle of *multiple* bytes that make up a single character, which in UTF-8 applies to any characters outside the ASCII range, such as `é`.

As of v7.0, `Get-Content` doesn't offer a way to read a specified number of *characters*, which is why the .NET `System.IO.StreamReader` type is used in the solution above.

Answer (score 4):

This will return a byte array.  In powershell 5 it's `-encoding byte`.

```
get-content file -AsByteStream -totalcount 50
```

Using powershell 5 and getting a string:

```
$a = get-content file -encoding byte -totalcount 50
-join [char[]]$a

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using PS 5.1. Using ```-encoding byte``` displayed what appears to be the first 20 characters by their decimal representation, one per line (eg. 60, 104).

Comment: `-join [char[]]$a` is convenient, but will only work if the text is ASCII-encoded (single-byte encoding with byte values only up to 127, no BOM).